# Getting TypeError from Terser when trying to build next.js sample app

Tags: build, next.js

When I set up a new next.js app following the setup section on https://github.com/zeit/next.js I get an error when trying to build.

Something in the line of:
Error: (client) static/chunks/commons.91235769179a31c41c74.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined...

I have a couple of next.js sites running in production without any problems. Haven't experienced this before.

I've set up a sample repo on GitHub:
https://github.com/wegeberg/next-terser-error

Below is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "next-terser-error",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  }
}
```

This is the most simple example I can produce. I would expect the "npm run build" to run without errors. But I get the above mentioned errors regardless of running the code on Mac or Debian.

Comment: Interesting. I am able to reproduce this. looking into it further

Comment: there's a thread here about this https://spectrum.chat/zeit/now/next-js-on-now-build-error~c73091bd-0141-4c3a-b8c1-3b8f7fa78298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/66#issue-406001469

I removed my `node_modules` folder, added this to `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
  "terser": "3.14.1"
}
```

re-installed, tried to build again and it worked.

Kudos to https://github.com/pitops

Comment: That did it. Using yarn simply add the above. With npm use https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions as suggested in the thread.